# Python/Tkinter: Destroying a window with a large canvas causes the program to stop responding

Tags: python, tkinter

I am maintaining a graphical parsing application written in Python with Tkinter. It optionally displays its results in a scrollable spreadsheet, which I create using a Canvas widget. However, it seems to have some scalability issues. When the main canvas is too big, trying to destroy the window in which the results are displayed causes the program to stop responding and need to be killed. When less data is being displayed, I can destroy it normally. Is this a known issue with Tkinter/large Canvi? Can I do anything to prevent these freezes?

```
#Function being called to destroy window
def justexit():
    savepopup.destroy() #Destroy the popup asking to save (that called this function)
    deleteall() #Destroy canvi and their contents
    popup.destroy() #Destroy the window containing all the canvi

def deleteall():
    for i, itemset in enumerate(items): #Items stores lists containing every item added to the canvi
        for item in itemset:
            canvi[i].delete(item)
        canvi[i].destroy()
```

And my estimation was a bit off. There are indeed up to tens of thousands of items in play, but I wouldn't expect the slowdown to be this glaring.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the canvas widget has scalability issues. Usually this doesn't kick in until you have tens of thousands of items on your canvas. How many items do you have?

I vaguely recall hearing that if you delete the items before deleting the canvas that it might go faster. I don't know that to be a fact, though.

Try running the following code. It creates 5000 random rectangles. When you click on the delete button it will delete the canvas widget, and on my machine this is instantaneous.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_geometry("400x400")
        self.del_button = tk.Button(text="delete", command=self.delete)
        self.del_button.pack()
        self.create_button = tk.Button(text="create", command=self.create)
        self.create_button.pack()
        self.canvas = None
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        if self.canvas is not None:
            self.canvas.destroy()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        colors = ["red","orange","green","blue", "violet","bisque","white"]
        for i in range(5000):
            x0 = random.random()*400
            y0 = random.random()*400
            width = random.randint(10,100)
            height = random.randint(10,100)
            x1 = x0 + width
            y1 = y0 + height
            color = colors.pop(0)
            colors.append(color)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1, outline="black", fill=color)
        
    def delete(self):
        self.canvas.destroy()
        self.canvas = None

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, I appear to be deleting the items before deleting the canvi...I didn't think I had more than 1,000 items on it.

Comment: @dpitch40: What do you mean by "appear to be deleting"? Either you are explicitly deleting them before destroying the canvas or you aren't. 1000 items shouldn't cause more than a second or two delay at worst. Is it possible you are continually creating objects and hiding old objects without actually deleting them? That's usually what happens when someone has this problem.

Comment: I save all of the items I create on each canvas (text and lines), then when deleting the window I iterate through where they are all stored and call the canvas' delete method on each one before destroying the canvas itself. However, I have determined that it hangs when destroying the window itself, not the canvi or anything on them. I can run your code just fine. I'll add some code relating to the destruction of the canvi.

Comment: @dpitch40: it may be that iterating over each one individually is what is taking so much time. Try not doing that, and just deleting the canvas. Or, do `self.canvas.delete("all")` to delete them all at once.

Comment: As I just said, the hangup is on the line popup.destroy().